# Strange NuGet behavior (works in some .csproj files but doesn't in others)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

So we use NuGet extensively, and before you tell me that's crazy I already know about most of the idiosyncrasys of NuGet and for the most part it does what we want with it. So please don't say "stop using NuGet as a solution"!

So here's the problem. We generate two versions of every NuGet package - a Debug version that includes the .pbd file so that we can trace into the program during debugging and a Release version that does not have the .pbd that we switch to near release. So I just did a mass change across all .csproj files from Release back to Debug and some of my projects are correctly using the debug version, but some are still pointing to the release version. I've closed the project (and Visual Studio) and reopened and re-built everything and cleaned out the .obj and bin folders and still when I look at the properties of some of the packages they are still pointing to Release. You can see in the picture below The first (top file) GEARVIEW QC.csproj is pointing to Debug in both the .csproj and the packages.config files and the properties correctly show the Debug version, but with others (QCImage in this case) the references is wrong. What the heck is going on here? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Strange NuGet behavior (works in some .csproj files but doesn't in others)

It is indeed a very strange behavior. I have created two package(Debug, Release), but not reproduce this issue. To troublestooting this issue, you can try the following steps:

- First, check if there any build error or yellow marker on the Reference node.
- Second, make sure the path in the properties is for the reference `Pacsgear.Debug.DICOMLIB` rather than `Pacsgear.Release.DICOMLIB`.
- Try to uninstall the nuget package and reinstall, check if it work for you.

Hope this helps.